# No input with rosclean purge?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to implement a scheduled process to periodically run `rosclean purge` when my logs get too big, but even though it's a command line tool, it seems to be hard-coded to require a user to answer a "yn" prompt. Most command line programs have a "--noinput" or "--assume-yes" option to allow the tool to be used in an automated process. How do you do this with rosclean?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281515/no-input-with-rosclean-purge?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2018-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

why not ask `rosclean` itself?

`rosclean purge -h` directly points you to the `-y` flag

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2018-02-01**:
Ah, thanks. I had checked `rosclean -h` but not `rosclean purge -h`.